# renaming multiple cells below a specific cell with pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to merge two Excel tables, but the rows don't line up because in one column information is split over several rows whereas in the other table it is contained in a single cell.

Is there a way with pandas to rename the cells in Table A so that they line up with the rows in  Table B?

```
df_jobs = pd.read_excel(r"jobs.xlsx", usecols="Jobs")
df_positions = pd.read_excel(r"orders.xlsx", usecols="Orders")
```

Sample files:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PEG3nZc0183Gh-8A2xbIs9kEZIWLzLSa/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HfQ4q7pjba0TKNJAHBqcGeoqdY3Yr3DB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Lutz. Additional informations on what you're trying to achieve (and how) could help others answer your question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: split this into two steps: 1) get both tables in the same format 2) do the join operation.

Comment: if you provide sample data (not an image) someone can definitely help

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have added two sample files.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your input data looks like:

```py
>>> df1
              A         i         j
0   O-20-003049       NaN       NaN
1             1  0.643284  0.834937
2             2  0.056463  0.394168
3             3  0.773379  0.057465
4             4  0.081585  0.178991
5             5  0.667667  0.004370
6             6  0.672313  0.587615
7   O-20-003104       NaN       NaN
8             1  0.916426  0.739700
9   O-20-003117       NaN       NaN
10            1  0.800776  0.614192
11            2  0.925186  0.980913
12            3  0.503419  0.775606

>>> df2
                A         x         y
0  O-20-003049.01  0.593312  0.666600
1  O-20-003049.02  0.554129  0.435650
2  O-20-003049.03  0.900707  0.623963
3  O-20-003049.04  0.023075  0.445153
4  O-20-003049.05  0.307908  0.503038
5  O-20-003049.06  0.844624  0.710027
6  O-20-003104.01  0.026914  0.091458
7  O-20-003117.01  0.275906  0.398993
8  O-20-003117.02  0.101117  0.691897
9  O-20-003117.03  0.739183  0.213401
```

We start by renaming the rows in column A:

```
# create a boolean mask
mask = df1["A"].str.startswith("O-")

# rename all rows
df1["A"] = df1.loc[mask, "A"].reindex(df1.index).ffill() \
           + "." + df1["A"].str.pad(2, fillchar="0")

# remove unwanted rows (where mask==True)
df1 = df1[~mask].reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
>>> df1
                 A         i         j
1   O-20-003049.01  0.000908  0.078590
2   O-20-003049.02  0.896207  0.406293
3   O-20-003049.03  0.120693  0.722355
4   O-20-003049.04  0.412412  0.447349
5   O-20-003049.05  0.369486  0.872241
6   O-20-003049.06  0.614941  0.907893
8   O-20-003104.01  0.519443  0.800131
10  O-20-003117.01  0.583067  0.760002
11  O-20-003117.02  0.133029  0.389461
12  O-20-003117.03  0.969289  0.397733
```

Now, we are able to merge data on column A:

```py
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on="A")
                A         i         j         x         y
0  O-20-003049.01  0.643284  0.834937  0.593312  0.666600
1  O-20-003049.02  0.056463  0.394168  0.554129  0.435650
2  O-20-003049.03  0.773379  0.057465  0.900707  0.623963
3  O-20-003049.04  0.081585  0.178991  0.023075  0.445153
4  O-20-003049.05  0.667667  0.004370  0.307908  0.503038
5  O-20-003049.06  0.672313  0.587615  0.844624  0.710027
6  O-20-003104.01  0.916426  0.739700  0.026914  0.091458
7  O-20-003117.01  0.800776  0.614192  0.275906  0.398993
8  O-20-003117.02  0.925186  0.980913  0.101117  0.691897
9  O-20-003117.03  0.503419  0.775606  0.739183  0.213401
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. Unfortunately, I get a 

"Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values" 

error when I run this on my files. I tried adding dtype="boolean" to my data frame, but then I get 

"Position cannot be cast to bool". 

Any ideas?